# Top level class extending an inner class

Tags: java, subclass, inner-classes

I understand the concept of a top-level class that extends an inner class:

```
package pkg1;
public class A {
    public class B {
    }
}

package pkg2;
import pk1.A;
public class C extends A.B {
    public C() {
        new A().super();
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out any real example that illustrates this. That is, why should we use such implementation?

Comment: Why Use Nested Classes? [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Are you sure this is for Java? Because this code will not compile. Java also cannot extend from multiple classes

Comment: For all those who say it won't compile: It does, the nested class has to be static tho. And for others who says multiple class inheritance isn't possible, it isn't. And no one says it is.

Comment: @Zizouz212 the whole catch is that it is not a static class and despite of that it actually compiles. Inner static is obvious.

Comment: Oh, I read the fullstop as a comma

Answer (score 4):

> That is, why should we use such implementation?

You shouldn't. If `C` has to create its own enclosing instance, then it is no longer semantically "inner".

This feature is more useful when you are passing the enclosing instance in, which behaves the same as an inner class:

```
class C extends A.B {
    C(A enclosing) {
        enclosing.super(); // note: invokes a constructor
    }                      //       of the B superclass
}
```

(Except we can't use a class instance creation expression like `someA.new C()`. We have to use `new C(someA)`.)

But if you find yourself having to use this, it probably means you've programmed yourself in to a corner. `B` should probably be a top-level class or `static` with the "enclosing instance" explicitly passed in.

Comment: @Claudio `enclosing.super()` does not invoke a constructor of `enclosing`, it invokes a constructor of the `B` superclass. So much confusion on this question...